LNK1104 cannot open file 'P7x64.dll.lib'
I've been given a project that uses external libraries, but it didn't come with them. I fixed a few issues, but now I've encountered an error. The program uses the Baical P7 library, but I can't figure out where to get P7x64.dll.lib. I searched on the Baical website and downloaded all downloadable but couldn't find p7x64.dll or p7x64.dll.lib file. Please if anyone knows where it's coming from.

I have no particular experience with this library but it looks to me that you are supposed to download the source code and build the libraries for yourself. Doing so requires knowledge of cmake.

Thank you for the comment. I have already downloaded and built it but no P7x64.dll output.
3>Speed.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Tiffany\Desktop\baical-master\baical-master\Binaries\Speed.exe ========== Rebuild All: 4 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

https://www.dllme.com/dll/files/p7x64

Thank you for the answer, but It complains about P7x64.dll.lib

@Tiffany I'm not sure what you are doing. How did you generate that speed.vcxproj project file?

@Tiffany Looks to me that the project you should be building is called p7 or p7lib.

@john I downloaded the source code from GitHub, opened it in Visual Studio, and just built it.

@Tiffany I'm looking at the download page on their website, but I have no idea.

@Tiffany The documentation does say that you use cmake.

@john ok I will look

Ok my best guess is that your P7x64.dll.lib is named manually. @john is right, you need to use CMake, to build p7 library. here is how:

Download cmake https://cmake.org/download/

Install and don't forget checkbox CHECKED where it says: add CMake to PATH.

Now download https://baical.net/downloads.html file P7 library vX.X

When you unarchive downloaded file it will give you a dir libP7Client_vX.X.

Go inside and open folder Sources, right click inside the folder, but on empty space and say Open in Terminal or open terminal/CMD independently and navigate to same folder using cd command.

When you are inside terminal and standing on correct source directory type: cmake --help.

It will generate command list, where, you are looking for Visual Studio 17 2022 = Generates Visual Studio 2022 project files. Use -A option to specify architecture. (You may have different versions)

When you find it, use command set below to generate "solution". It is copied from documentation:
mkdir "build"
cd "build"
cmake -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" ".."
It may be slightly different for you but it will be basically the same. Modify and use it.

When you do this it should give you new solution in _build_ folder.

Now open freshly generated p7.sln which is sitting inside _build_ folder into Visual Studio and build like regular solution. It should give you you library, which probably will be named p7.lib.

You can now rename p7.lib to P7x64.dll.lib and put somewhere you think is better.

Go to options where you link various 3rd party library dirs (I assume you know how to do that, based you have already done some of libraries).


I'm not best documentation writer and I know it's a lot but whatever, hope it helps.

That did work! I had to make it a hundred times to get it worked, but it worked. Thank you so much!
